Dialogue about a sushi place serving only the chef's choice
I remember a scene with upper middle class couples having a dinner at the female main character's boyfriend's place. They're having a conversation about something like there being too many choices in life. One of the supporting women then tells about a sushi place where there is only two items on the menu: the chef's choice or leave.
I think the boyfriend was a widower and after the conversation the main character realizes that she's the first woman he has brought to dine with his friends after his wife's death. She has some second thoughts about the relationship and so on.
I can't remember if it was a tv show or a film. For some reason I'm thinking the woman wasn't the only main character, which makes me think about a tv show, but it might've been just a film with many characters.
I think it is quite recent anyway, at least in the 2000's. I see a lot of foreign films but this was probably English speaking, so either US of British.

Do you remember what any of the characters looked like?

I think the main character was brunette, but this might be false. Just normal, hollywood-like beautiful actors in their 30's I guess.

I forgot about this for a while but I finally figured it out. It was
Weeds, season 8 episode 10: "Threshold"
Main character is Nancy Botwin and the boyfriend is Rabbi Dave Bloom. The dialogue goes like this:

Nancy: What's Toroshiki?
Female friend: Oh, new sushi place. Yeah, the menu has only two options, the "Have Faith," which is chef's choice, and the "Don't Have Faith," which is directions to the closest McDonald's. It's awesome, right?
Nancy: If you don't have trust issues.
Male friend #1: You know, it's really beautiful when you don't have to make a decision. I mean, to just sit down, eat, - and you know it's gonna be delicious? It's worth it.
Male friend #2: You know what? Too many choices? It makes people miserable.

